# Use array to extract variables in widget logic

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget

In website [www.hermeias.eu/locations](http://www.hermeias.eu/locations) I have widgets with tour locations. Now I want to divide them in 2 groups and extract individual locations to each of them.

My current code is:

```
is_page('locations')|| is_slugs('ljubljana', 'austria', 'hungary')
```

for widget to appear in locations page.[Widget section image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8I46.png)
Locations are identified as slugs as seen here:[Locations and slugs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIFFT.png)

Comment: Hi. What are you using to create function `is_slugs` ?

Comment: I am trying to array slugs of the locations to appear in the widget.

Comment: `is_slugs` is not a wordpress function that I can find in the function reference. Where are you getting that from, and what is the code for it?

Comment: I wanted to select specific locations of the tour that are grouped under slugs. Which function do I have to use to select specific locations  of the tour? thank you!

Comment: is_page can get you pages, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/ and you can use slugs as parameters, including an array of slugs.  You can use this to find "if is slug" https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42117/how-do-i-retrieve-the-slug-of-the-current-page